# Cakephp : generate links in a menu

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

In a view I have this foreach for generates links

```
 <ul class="nav">
  <?php foreach($menus as $k => $menu): ?>

    <li>
      <a href="information/index/<?php echo $menu['Menu']['slug']; ?>">
        <i class="<?php echo $menu['Menu']['icon-type']; ?> icon-large"></i>
        <?php echo $menu['Menu']['name']; ?>
      </a>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

which give

- MenuA
- MenuB
- MenuC

So That I could access localhost/folder/information/index/menuA
I have a problem with this line

```
<a href="information/index/<?php echo $menu['Menu']['slug']; ?>">
```

Each time a click on  the menu the link will be incremented the Controller and the Action

```
http://localhost/folder/information/index/information/index/menuA
```

Comment: You should use the CakePHP Menu Helper, or at the very least use the HTMLHelper to create your links... http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/alkemann/2009/02/04/menuhelper

Comment: Thks Scrowlerfor the info!

Comment: So, what is the specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="nav">
 <?php foreach($menus as $k => $menu): ?>
  <li>
  <?php
      echo $this->Html->link("<i class='".$menu['Menu']['icon-type']." icon-large'></i>".$menu['Menu']['name'],array('controller' => 'information', 'action' => 'index', $menu['Menu']['slug']), array('escape' => false));
  ?>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use CakePHP HTML helper to generate the link.
If you really want to use the static ones in your case, put a heading "/" in front.

```
<a href="/information/index/<?php echo $menu['Menu']['slug']; ?>">
```